# Rails- Index in form_for field names

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, form-for

I have a form that I am trying to build to edit multiple records.  It's complicated, doesn't map straight to the database, and there can be any number of records.  I have the code written so all of the data is passed to the view as a hash.  Like this:

```
 @formdata = {"datafield_1"=>"value_1", "datafield_2"=>"value_2"}
```

What I want to do is to create something like:

```
 f.textfield :datafield_1
 f.textfield :datafield_2
 f.textfield :datafield_3
 etc. etc. etc.
```

But I don't know how to pass the index of my for loop into the variable name.  In short, how do I do :datafield_i where i is my index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% %w(1 2 3).each do |i| %>
  <%= f.textfield(:"datafield_#{i}") -%>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% @formdata.keys.each do |datafield| %>
  <%= f.textfield(datafield.to_sym) -%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Take that back, this     <%=  concat(f.input :"start_date_#{i}"), input_html: { value: @ratesform["start_date_1"]} %>  says it is missing a ) at the comma before input_html

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.  I can use concat to make a string and then the to_sym to make the variable.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: <% concat('foo') %> and <%= 'foo' -%> are the same.